# Why does substitute() create line breaks when none exist in argument?

Tags: r

Consider following R command:

```
> substitute(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1)
```

Why did the output break across lines?  Didn't see anything in `help("substitute")` about any kind of size or width cutoff.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Just so you know, the way something is displayed on the console will have absolutely nothing to do with `substitute`. What you're seeing is the result of a call to `print`, probably `print.default`. I don't see anything obvious, so it's probably happening internally in the C code of the print method.

Comment: Oddly enough though, even if you shrink the width of the console window, it will insert an extra break before the last `1` no matter what.

Comment: Ah, there is it in `?print.default`. Try setting `options(deparse.cutoff = 200)` or some such large number. Specifically, the line from the documentation is: `option deparse.cutoff controls the printing of language objects such as calls and formulae.`.

Comment: Ahh, I see it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `substitute`. The `substitute` function simply returns an object of class "call". The default `print()` method is then used to "draw" this "call" to the console. The function formats the code to "look pretty". In this case it makes sure the lines of text obey a cut off of around 60 characters.

You can change the default cutoff by setting an `option()`

```
options("deparse.cutoff"=120)
```

Now if you try it again, you will get the full line

```
substitute(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
# c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```